# Are arrow functions specifics valid for Angular Component context?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I know the topic with the arrow functions is discussed a lot but couldn't find an answer to the following use case.

This example is from Angular 4 Directive:

```
export class MouseParallaxDirective implements AfterViewInit  {

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) { 
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Here `this` points at the angular component object
    let movementStrength = 25;
    let height = movementStrength / window.innerHeight;
    let width = movementStrength / window.innerWidth;
    let parallaxElement = this.element.nativeElement;

    window.onmousemove = (e) => {
      // Here `this` points at the `window` object
      let pageX = e.pageX - (window.innerWidth / 2);
      let pageY = e.pageY - (window.innerHeight / 2);
      let newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
      let newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
      parallaxElement.style.backgroundPosition = newvalueX +"px " + newvalueY + "px";
    };

  }
}
```

Shouldn't both `this`s point at the same object after the arrow function keeps the outer scope?

Comment: Can you reproduce it?

Comment: "*Here `this` points at the `window` object*" - how do you conclude that? Does your debugger tell this? What is your transpilation target, ES5? Since your function does not use `this` anywhere, it probably simply isn't captured at all.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I've used `debugger` in order to capture the `this`.

Comment: @z_lander IIRC there's a bug in the devtools that shows wrong `this` values, at least when the code in the arrow function doesn't use `this` as well. Also when you compile Typescript to ES5 you won't be able to access the arrow function's `this` value, you would need to compile your Typescript code to ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `onmousemove` belongs to the window object, so inside this function the `this` will refer to the window object.

same for the function `ngAfterViewInit` which is declared in the scope of the component `MouseParallaxDirective` that's why in this case the this refers to that component.

so the two `this`'s in this case cannot refer to the same object.

But you still has access to the outside scope, as shown here when declaring a variable inside the component, we can access it inside the `onmousemove` function.

[image]

We can see that a `_this` is created to have access to the component scope

**Scopes:**

[image]

Demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5u6zid?file=app/mouseParallaxDirective/MouseParallaxDirective.component.ts

Comment: @yurzui: you mean the context is the same ? I'm looking at it.

Comment: @HDJEMAI Thank you for the explanation and the examples. I ended up using extra variable in order to keep track of the value I need from the outer scope.

Answer (score 2):

The `ngAfterViewInit` method is invoked from the **instance** of `MouseParallaxDirective` `class`, which is basically the prototype pattern behind the scenes.
This means that `this` will refer to the `class` instance.

The `this` context is defined in a dynamic way, we should actually ask our-self *"What is the calling object?"*

There are four rules do determine the context of `this`:

1. [When a function is "living" in the global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call), the value of
   `this` inside of that function will be the window object (only in none
   `strict mode`).
2. [When a function is called by a preceding dot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method),   i.e:
   `myObj.myFunc()`
   The object before that dot is `this` (`myObj === this` in this case).
3. When we use `.call`, `.apply` or `.bind`, `this` [is explicitly
   defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#The_bind_method).
4. [When a constructor function is used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_constructor) (with the `new` keyword), `this`
   refers to the specific instance of the object that is created and
   returned by the `constructor` function.

**Since ES2015** came out, [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions) use a different mechanism, and `this` is no longer defined in a dynamic way.

> `this` retains the value of the enclosing **LEXICAL** context's this...

By the way, that is the reason we can't and shouldn't use arrow functions when adding functions to a prototype, because we won't be able to use `this` properly.
For example, **never** do this pattern:

```
Array.prototype.mySort = () => {// this is not referenced to the array}
```

In your case, the anonymous arrow function of `window.onmousemove` will refer to the `class` instance because this is its lexical context.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the advice but the anonymous arrow function of `window.onmousemove` is _not_ referring to the `class` instance but to the `window` object and this was my initial concern.